# Как защитить личные данные пользователя

Tags: wpf, mongodb

Я пишу программу на WPF.NET с базой MongoDB. Скажем у меня есть коллекция PersonalProfiles в которой есть документы. Каждый документ это по сути личные данные профиля определенного клиента(User). В этих данных я храню различную информацию, которая не должна попасть в чужие руки. При помощи ролей я могу ограничить другого пользователя чтоб он не мог удалить или переписать данные, но эта роль у всех(Program Client), а значит прочитать данные могут все друг у друга. Я к тому что если какой-то из пользователей не такой уж и честный, он может сделать подключение через C# Console + MongoDB и прочитать чужие данные from PersonalProfiles.

*Какие выводы я сделал чтобы это решить:*
**1.** Я могу данные записать в User.customData пользователя, но я не знаю,  правильно ли всю личную информацию туда писать, тем более это не два слова.
**2.** Или я могу данные хранить в зашифрованом виде через токен, который могу хранить в User.customData и при каждом заходе в программу получая документ буду его расшифровывать через этот токен.

> Я хочу знать что я пишу правильно, а не придумываю велосипед. Хочу
>   совет, как мне зашифровать или защитить личные данные пользователя.

Comment: Касаемо второго сценария: что мешает злоумышленнику взять токен из user.CustomData и расшифровать данные?

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос. Я это упустил, но уже проверил. У меня есть роль с привилегиями changeOwnCustomData, find, listCollections, и простой юзер не видет других пользователей в базе. Если использовать db.getUser("<some user name>") для поиска других пользователей вы получите ошибку выполнения. Но если вы напишете так db.getUser("myname") то вы увидете только свои данные и тот токен который вы там храните в customData, вить он только ваш и если кто то будет менять свои данные, какая мне разница? Хочешь ломать сам себя, ну и пусть ломает, главное чтоб остальные не пострадали.